# Use of propertyName parameter in Delegates.observable

Tags: kotlin

The syntax for Delegates.observable in Kotlin consist of "propertyName, oldValue , newValue".

```
var name: String by Delegates.observable("no name") {
        d, old, new ->
        println("$old - $new")
    }
```

However, when I try to reuse the same observable for bunch of properties it won't work.

e.g

```
 private val observablePropertyDelegate 
= Delegates.observable("<none>")
     { pName, oldValue, newValue ->println("$pName is updated,$oldValue to $newValue")
            }
   var name: String by observablePropertyDelegate
   var name1: String by observablePropertyDelegate
   var name2: String  by observablePropertyDelegate
```

What confuses me is if we can not re-use the Observable delegates for different properties, then why does it contain the property name? Is there any particular reason?

Why not following:

```
private val observablePropertyDelegate 
    = Delegates.observable("myOwnProperty","<none>")
         { oldValue, newValue ->println("myOwnProperty is updated,$oldValue to $newValue")
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say it does not work?

This code:

```
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

class Test {
    private val observablePropertyDelegate
        = Delegates.observable("<none>")
    { pName, oldValue, newValue ->println("$pName is updated, $oldValue to $newValue")}

    var name: String by observablePropertyDelegate
    var name1: String by observablePropertyDelegate
    var name2: String  by observablePropertyDelegate
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test = Test()

    test.name = "a"
    test.name1 = "b"
    test.name2 = "c"

    test.name = "d"
    test.name1 = "e"
    test.name2 = "f"
}
```

outputs this:

```
property name (Kotlin reflection is not available) is updated, <none> to a
property name1 (Kotlin reflection is not available) is updated, a to b
property name2 (Kotlin reflection is not available) is updated, b to c
property name (Kotlin reflection is not available) is updated, c to d
property name1 (Kotlin reflection is not available) is updated, d to e
property name2 (Kotlin reflection is not available) is updated, e to f
```

which seems fine to me considering `name`, `name1` and `name2` are essentially aliases for the same field - this is the same situation as if you used the same backing field for mutliple properties.

As for why property name is assed to the delegate - how else would you know which property was used to access the field? Also in your first example the delegate still prints correct message if you change the property name. However in the second one you need to remember to update delegate if change property name to make suer message stays correct.

Comment: No it does work. Let me elobrate. In the above example, if you re-use 'observablePropertyDelegate' then it would be invoked for all the properties. for e.g.For property 'name' it is --> <none> to a , now for property 'name1' its 'a' to 'b' and not <none> to 'b'. The point I am trying to make is all properties are using same instance. And if I want separate instance then it would not do any value add for 'propertyName' parameter as it would be specific to one property(would be known at compile time!)

Comment: Reread the last two sentences in my answer. If you use the property name in the delegate (eg. for logging purposes) then if it is not provided as paramater you need to adjust your delegate code manually if your property name changes for some reason (eg. refactoring). Also I neglected to mention that the first parameter is not actually the prperty namee, bu a KProperty<*> instance - which may be necessary for some advanced processing of the value change event.